# vb.net 2008 - windows service won't execute vbs in process

Tags: vb.net, service, process, vbscript

I've been trying off and on for a week now to get this to work but no luck.  I have completely stripped down my vb.net 2008 windows service to just create a vbs file and launch it using a process.  Can someone please help?  I'm dying here.  The vbs file creates and is valid.  I can execute it manually, the windows service just won't run it!!  I'm on a windows 7 machine and the process is compiled and installed as a 32 bit process.  It is also installed as local system.

After the process tries to execute, I created a text file and it did so successfully.  So, I know that the service isn't crashing out.

Any ideas?

Cheers,
J

```
Dim TextFile As New StreamWriter("C:\LRQuadrant\" & "john" & ".vbs")

'Create the VBS file - won't work in .Net
TextFile.WriteLine("Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject(""WScript.Shell"")")
TextFile.WriteLine("ScenFile = """ & "john" & """")
TextFile.WriteLine("Set LRE = WScript.CreateObject (""WLRun.LrEngine"")")
TextFile.WriteLine("WScript.Sleep 5000")
TextFile.WriteLine("if LRE.Scenario.IsOpened then")
TextFile.WriteLine("While LRE.Scenario.IsActive")
TextFile.WriteLine("Wscript.Sleep 10000")
TextFile.WriteLine("Wend")
TextFile.WriteLine("end if")
TextFile.WriteLine("LRE.Scenario.Open ScenFile, SAVE_CURRENT")
TextFile.WriteLine("DateString = Year(Date) &  
  Right(""0"" & Month(Date), 2) &  
  Right(""0"" & Day(Date), 2) &""_""& 
  Right(""0"" & Hour(Now),2) & Right(""0"" & 
  Minute(Now),2)")
TextFile.WriteLine("ResultDir =  ""C:\LRQuadrant\""")
TextFile.WriteLine("LRE.Scenario.ResultDir = ResultDir")
TextFile.WriteLine("If LRE.Scenario.Start = 0 Then")
TextFile.WriteLine("While LRE.Scenario.IsActive")
TextFile.WriteLine("Wscript.Sleep 10000")
TextFile.WriteLine("Wend")
TextFile.WriteLine("end if")
TextFile.WriteLine("if Not LRE.Scenario.IsResultsCollated then")
TextFile.WriteLine("LRE.Scenario.CollateResults")
TextFile.WriteLine("end if")
TextFile.WriteLine("while not LRE.Scenario.IsResultsCollated")
TextFile.WriteLine("Wscript.Sleep 10000")
TextFile.WriteLine("wend")
TextFile.WriteLine("LRE.CloseController()")
TextFile.Close()

Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)

Process.Start("C:\LRQuadrant\john.vbs")

Dim TextFile2 As New StreamWriter("C:\LRQuadrant\bugger.txt")
TextFile2.WriteLine("hello")
TextFile2.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `WaitForExit()`.
Otherwise, you'll try to read the file before the process finishes.

Answer (score 1):

VBS files are not executable files. They are interpreted scripts. So you will need to call cscript.exe and pass your VBS file as an argument:

```
cscript.exe //B //Nologo C:\LRQuadrant\john.vbs
```

Or possibly the full path:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cscript.exe //B //Nologo C:\LRQuadrant\john.vbs
```

If that doesn't work quite right, you can try this:

```
%comspec% /C cscript.exe //B //Nologo C:\LRQuadrant\john.vbs
```

Good luck.

Comment: The System folder should always be in the path. You definitely should **not** hard-code the value here (or anywhere).